# organizing query result in sql developer (oracle 11g)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, subquery

Currently i have a table called `schedule` in db (SQL developer).

Assuming the`availableID`s are 1,3,7,8. The table consists of something like this:

```
Stud        Title   Supervisor  Examiner    availableID    
abc         Hello     1024       1001           1
def         Hi        1024       1001           1
ghi         Hey       1002       1004           1 
xxx         hhh       1020       1011           1
jkl         hhh       1027       1010           1
try         ttt       1001       1011           1
654         bbb       1007       1012           1
gyg         888       1027       1051           1
yyi         333       1004       1022           3
fff         111       1027       1041           3
ggg         222       1032       1007           3
hhh         444       1007       1001           3
ppp         444       1005       1072           7
ooo         555       1067       1009           7
uuu         666       1030       1010           7
yyy         777       1004       1001           7
qqq         yhh       1015       1072           8
www         767       1017       1029           8
eee         566       1030       1020           8
rrr         888       1004       1031           8
abc         5555      1045       1051           8
```

As you can see, I have sort these value using `ORDER BY availableID asc`.
However, I would like to ORGANIZE them again into something like this:

```
    Stud        Title   Supervisor  Examiner    availableID    
    abc         Hello     1024       1001           1
    def         Hi        1024       1001           1
    ghi         Hey       1002       1004           1 
    xxx         hhh       1020       1011           1
    yyi         333       1004       1022           3
    fff         111       1027       1041           3
    ggg         222       1032       1007           3
    hhh         444       1007       1001           3
    ppp         444       1005       1072           7
    ooo         555       1067       1009           7
    uuu         666       1030       1010           7
    yyy         777       1004       1001           7
    qqq         yhh       1015       1072           8
    www         767       1017       1029           8
    eee         566       1030       1020           8
    rrr         888       1004       1031           8
    jkl         hhh       1027       1010           1
    try         ttt       1001       1011           1
    654         bbb       1007       1012           1
    gyg         888       1027       1051           1
    ........
    abc         5555      1045       1051           8
```

For every `availableID` it will called four times then proceed to next `availableID`. Next it will iterate back to the lowest ID but using different other values. `Stud` must be distinct.

Is it possible to achieve this by using sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` and some arithmetic.  Something like:

```
Select t.*
From (select t.*,
             Row_number() over (partition by availableid order by stud) as seqnum 
      From t
     ) t
Order by trunc((seqnum - 1) / 4), availableid
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time. The second select query, should I add all columns that i want to display?

Comment: I have a question... What changes should I make if i want to sort by using `availableID` AND `availableDate`?

Comment: @user6308605 . . . Your question has no column at all called `availableDate`.  I would suggest that you ask another question with relevant data and results.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly another equivalent approach as above, using floor and partitioning and grouping by the same availableID column -

```
select a.stud,
       a.title,
       a.supervisor, 
       a.examiner,
       a.availableID 
from ( select s.*,row_number() over (partition by availableID order by availableID) rn 
       from student s) a 
order by floor((rn-1)/4),availableID
```

---

Comment: Hi Thank you! It is working well too. I wish I can vote up for your answer :D